# Syntax error from running another file by exec (language C)(edit)

Tags: c, syntax-error, exec

I'm experimenting with the family exec.

The first code is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Program changes permission because exec can't execute the file if permission is not accurated
    chmod("src2/child.c", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXU);

    // Now program creates one child process
    pid_t pid = fork();

    // If fork failed exit with error
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("error in fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execlp("src2/child.c", "child.c", "Ciao");
        // if execlp return something is error
        perror("error in exec");
        exit(1);
    }
    // father exit
    exit(0);
}
```

The file child.c is:

```
int child(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // write the term passed
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(0);
}
```

The makefile compiled both of the file. But in running, the terminal return 'src2/child.c: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected'
I don't understand why

Comment: You are trying to run the C source code, not the compiled program.

Comment: How did you get to a multi-process programming without knowing the basics? "Hello world" program won't run this way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `src2/child.c` isn't a binary and doesn't have a shebang (`#!`) line, the shell expects the file to contain shell commands to execute. But it does not.

You need to execute `trygame` (an executable), not `src2/child.c` (part of the source code used to create that executable).

---

You have previously [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544031/syntax-error-from-running-another-file-by-exec) that the C file in question is part of a project that includes a `make` file. This `make` file directs `make` to executes the following:

```bash
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -I./inc -c src/main.c      -o src/main.o
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -I./inc -c src/errExit.c   -o src/errExit.o
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -I./inc -c src/semaphore.c -o src/semaphore.o
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -I./inc -c src/child.c     -o src/child.o

gcc src/main.o src/errExit.o src/semaphore.o src/child.o -o trygame
```

This compiles four files found in `src/` and links them into an executable named `trygame`.

You apparently  renamed `src` to `src2` and will need to adjust the `make` file accordingly. Once that's done, run `make` to generate the `trygame` executable.

To run the program, you need to execute this `trygame`, not `src2/child.c`.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved now. Only: I had adjusted the file correctly. 
The problem was effectively (as you said) that I can't use exec on a c file. I misunderstood the exec family.